# Uso de CASE en SQL Server

Tags: sql, server

Estimados: Tengo que insertar en el ultimo registro la cantidad de registros de la tabla pero la complejidad es que ese valor tiene que tener 6 posiciones, por eso realice el siguiente script pero me da error de sintaxis en el '<'

```
insert into base.dbo.tabla1 (campo)
select
case count (campo)
when count (campo) < '10' then concat ('00000',count (campo)) 
when count (campo) < '100' then concat ('0000',count (campo))
when count (campo) < '1000' then concat ('000',count (campo))
when count (campo) < '10000' then concat ('00',count (campo))
when count (campo) < '100000' then concat ('0',count (campo))
else count (campo)
from base.dbo.tabla1
```

Comment: Tienes algunos errores en tu query: luego del `CASE` hay un `count(campo)` que no va, te falta el `END` al final del `CASE`, comparas el count(campo) que es de tipo entero con valores que son cadenas (deberías sacarle las comillas simples).

Comment: Exacto, en todo caso debería ser `else '' end`

Answer (score 1):

Una forma mas sencilla de resolverlo podría ser:

Primero le concatena 5 ceros (a la izquierda) al total de registros (previamente convertido a tipo cadena) y luego obtiene los últimos 6 dígitos (los 6 primeros dígitos contando desde la derecha).

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(count(campo) AS varchar(10)), 6)
FROM base.dbo.tabla1;

ó

SELECT RIGHT(concat('00000', count(campo)), 6)
FROM base.dbo.tabla1;
```

El problema con esta query es que si count(*) devolviera un número con mas de 6 dígitos, lo terminaría cortando y retornando solo los últimos 6 dígitos.